# Set result of computation to be percent in ng-style tag Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
    <div class="vote-percent-container" flex layout="row">
        <div class="percent-red"  ng-style="'width: (vm.lcs.redVotes / vm.lcs.voteSum) * 100%'"></div>
        <div class="percent-blue" ng-style="'width: (vm.lcs.blueVotes / vm.lcs.voteSum) * 100%'"></div>
    </div>
```

How can i set the width of the div to the value of the computation and still set it to percent. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can't multiply by `100%`, it's a string.

Comment: please copy&paste your CODE, not try to upload an image of some code

Comment: ok i'll do that in the future

Comment: no, not in the future. please edit your question so that other people who come here in a few months/years will be able to read your question even if the link will become dead

Comment: why did you post the code of the answer instead of the code of your question???

Comment: Dude chill. I noticed but had to edit it back. I'm new to stack overflow, cut me some slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrapping your style in a string. It supposed to be an object with keys as CSS properties and values as their values. Also, add the "%" after you're done calculating the actual number.

Try this :

```
<div class="percent-red" ng-style="{'width' : ((vm.lcs.redVotes / vm.lcs.voteSum) * 100 ) + '%'}" > </div>
```

And look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for more documentation.